# Accumulated sum in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

Do we have a way to make an accumulated sum in SPARQL that is not reduced?

For instance,

```
SELECT ?p WHERE {
  VALUES ?p { 1 1 2 }
}
ORDER BY ?p
```

would result in 1 2 4, - rather than 4.

Comment: If I'm not totally wrong, that's not possible in a SPARQL query. From my point of view at some point client-side code is the only way to go as SPARQL is just a query language for RDF data and not something like R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate accumulated sums in the absense of RDF data ('`FROM DUAL`'), it is impossible:

- [SPARQL list syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#collections) is [not allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rInlineData) in `VALUES`,
- `VALUES` themself  are [unordered](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_sparqlSolutionSequence).

---

However, if values are present in RDF data, it is possible to calculate their accumulated sums.

Consider the following example.

*Input data*

```sql
INSERT DATA {
  ex:st ex:order "1"^^xsd:integer ;
        ex:value "1"^^xsd:integer .     
  ex:nd ex:order "2"^^xsd:integer ;
        ex:value "1"^^xsd:integer .
  ex:rd ex:order "3"^^xsd:integer ;
        ex:value "2"^^xsd:integer .
}
```

*Query*

```sql
SELECT
(SAMPLE(?v1) AS ?v)
(SUM(?v2) AS ?acc)
WHERE {
  ?e1 ex:order ?o1 ; ex:value ?v1 .
  ?e2 ex:order ?o2 ; ex:value ?v2 .
  FILTER (?o1 >= ?o2)
} GROUP BY ?e1 ORDER BY ASC(SAMPLE(?o1))
```

*Output*

```
  v                   acc               
 ------------------- ------------------ 
  "1"^^xsd:integer    "1"^^xsd:integer  
  "1"^^xsd:integer    "2"^^xsd:integer  
  "2"^^xsd:integer    "4"^^xsd:integer
```

The values in the example above are ordered explicitly, but it is not very hard to write a query when values are ordered implicitly (as in ABC analysis).

---

Let us consider another example, which uses [Turtle list syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#collections).

*Input data*

```sql
INSERT DATA {
  ex:data ex:values (1 1 2)
}
```

*Query*

```sql
SELECT
(SAMPLE(?v2) AS ?v)
(SUM(?v1) AS ?acc)
WHERE { 
  ex:data ex:values/rdf:rest* ?e1 .
                              ?e1 rdf:first ?v1 .
                              ?e1 rdf:rest* ?e2 .
                              ?e2 rdf:first ?v2 .
} GROUP BY (?e2) ORDER BY(COUNT(?e1))
```

*Output*

```
  v                   acc               
 ------------------- ------------------ 
  "1"^^xsd:integer    "1"^^xsd:integer  
  "1"^^xsd:integer    "2"^^xsd:integer  
  "2"^^xsd:integer    "4"^^xsd:integer
```