# Passing arbitrary number of parameters to a SPARQL query

Tags: jquery, sparql, virtuoso

I have several SPARQL queries that need to get user parameters one or more URIs or text values. The SPARQL queries are in Virtuoso re-write rules. To illustrate this I'll use a query to DBpedia, asking for the philosophers born today and in the following 7 days.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

#all philosophers born today and in the next 7 days with influences

SELECT DISTINCT   ?name  ?wikipedia_page ?born  (Group_Concat(DISTINCT ?influencerSTR; separator = "\n") as ?influenced_by) (Group_Concat(DISTINCT ?_influencedSTR; separator = '\n') as ?influenced) ?full_description_in_dbpedia #?influenced ?ideas  ?indegree ?person

WHERE {

 {?person rdf:type o:Philosopher ;
         rdfs:label ?label;
         ^foaf:primaryTopic ?wikipedia_page ;
         o:birthDate ?born ;
     o:influencedBy|^o:influenced ?influencer.}

values ?d {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7}

BIND ((SUBSTR(STR(?born),6) as ?bornSTR))
BIND ((SUBSTR(STR(bif:dateadd("day", ?d, now())),6,5)) as ?day)

FILTER (STRLEN(STR(?born)) > 6 &&  STR(?bornSTR) = STR(?day))
FILTER (lang(?label) = "en") .

OPTIONAL {?person o:influenced|^o:influencedBy ?_influenced.} 
OPTIONAL {?person o:abstract ?abstract . FILTER (lang(?abstract) = "en") .}

BIND (str(?label)  AS ?name)
BIND (str(?abstract)  AS ?description)
BIND (STRAFTER((STR(?influencer)), "resource/") as ?influencerSTR ).
BIND (STRAFTER((STR(?_influenced)), "resource/") as ?_influencedSTR ).
BIND (?person AS ?full_description_in_dbpedia)

}

GROUP BY  ?name  ?wikipedia_page ?born ?day ?full_description_in_dbpedia
ORDER BY ?day
```

So, **ignoring if this particular example query is optimal**, how to change the query so that it could accept various parameters, for example `{1 4}` or `{0 5 6 7}`.

And I'm not saying that "VALUES should be used". It was just the first thing that I thought of. Any other suggestions are more than welcome.

Please note that if I put

```
values (?d) {("0") ("1") }
```

the query doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding `values (?d) {("0") ("1") }` -> what means doesn't work? It has to be an integer value, i.e. `values (?d) {(0) (1)}` which works perfectly for me on DBpedia endpoint.

Comment: Regarding the question in general. What does not work with your current solution?

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov, SPARQL list syntax is not allowed in `VALUES`. Lists can't be values in `VALUES`, if you are talking about something like this. Perhaps this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44440966/7879193

Comment: Both `values (?d) {(0) (1)}` and `values ?d {0 1}` appear to work (no error).  Neither `values ?d {(0) (1)}`, `values (?d) {0 1}`, nor `values (?d) {("0") ("1")}` appear to work (varying errors). If you mean more by "doesn't work" than "produces an error," I think you'll need to provide more detail including showing us what you're getting vs what you expect to get.

Comment: @AKSW @TallTed yes indeed `values (?d) {(0) (1)}` works, and of course `values (?d) {("0") ("1") }` shouldn't while I was wrongly expecting it to. Thanks! Now, as I see that I can pass the list of parameters without using space as delimiter, I'll try again and will update here if I still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be to use one of these forms (for the integer values in the example) --

- `values (?d) {(0) (1)}`
- `values ?d {0 1}`